# Hololens - Cant add external dll (IdentityModel.dll)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, identityserver4, hololens

i've been developing a Hololens app. We have an identityServer4 and using the Device Code flow, i can log a user. Everything works fine in the editor, but when I build the project for UWP, it fail.

I know the issue is with the dll files. Under Assets/Plugins, I added IdentityModel.dll and System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll. 
Each time I build I get this error :

UnityException: Failed to run serialization weaver with command "-pdb" "-verbose" "-unity-engine=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.CoreModule.dll" "Temp\StagingArea\TempSerializationWeaver" "-lock=UWP\project.lock.json" "@C:\Users\MAXIME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1bcc9fbb.tmp" "-additionalAssemblyPath=Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed".

Here the links to the dll ive been trying to add :
 https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/3.10.6
 https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encodings.Web/

So far, I tried different versions of the dlls 4.5 and standard2.0. I tried different way to add the dlls and different emplacement.

I'm stuck now. If you have any hints, thank you !

Comment: Are you building using .NET or IL2CPP?  It might be worth trying IL2CPP if you're not already.

Comment: Im using .net. I'm a bit confused what IL2CPP is. All microsoft tutorials where on .Net.
Unity version is 2018.3.6f on .net 4.x

Comment: [IL2CPP](https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/11127/deploy-hololens-projects-using-il2cpp-instead-of-net) will eventually replace .NET.  Under PlayerSettings > Scripting Backend you can make the change.  The difference is to do with how Unity takes your C# or UNityScript and turns it into a native binary - it doesn't change how you write your unity game, and should be a behind the scenes thing.  It's a shot in the dark, but many other peoples build problems don't occur under IL2CPP, so I'd say worth a shot.

Comment: @Jethro I switched to IL2CPP and its working. Im able to deploy with all my dlls.

Comment: @Jethro I switched to IL2CPP and its working. Im able to deploy with all my dlls.
For now I have a new issue (it was working before and still working in the editor). All my api call using httpclient extentions method from IdentityModel are not working and always return null.
Now my settings are :
- runtime : .net 4x
- Backend : IL2CPP
- Api compatibility .net 4.x

Comment: @Jethro Same for my NLog dll. The are no log files

Comment: Glad it's deploying OK!  Best to make a new question for the httpclient problem (: